# In Akka how do you know which request timed out?

Tags: timeout, akka

This is how a callback is assigned for failure

```
future.onFailure(new FailureHandler(), context().system().dispatcher());
```

In the method FailureHandler()

```
public final class FailureHandler extends OnFailure {
    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println(throwable.toString());
    }
}
```

I can't figure out a way to find out which request failed. This is a common requirement and I believe I am missing something trivial.

Comment: The request that failed is the one that resulted in you getting that `Future`, probably via `ask`.  If your failure handler is a piece of common code then supply it with more context (like what the request was) when constructing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was trivial indeed, need to declare a class level variable to hold the transactionId onFailure

```
public final class FailureHandler extends OnFailure {
    String transactionId;
    public FailureHandler(String transactionId){
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
        logger.error(transactionId + " failed");
    }
}
```